# Software to merge/organize multiple iterations of a music library

Tags: windows, file-management, media-manager

Many computers, backups, external drives, etc. have left me with multiple iterations of my music library. On top of that I have a couple different backups of my dad's music collection (which has many duplicates with my own), music dumps from friends, and so on. I am looking for a tool that can merge all these different iterations with varying, mismatched hierarchies into one one master collection of all my media files, from which I can then prune the duplicates and get down to enjoying my music. Since this would be a (mostly) once-off affair, I don't need something that can serve as an ongoing music manager (though if the tool that does the job also happens to be a proper music player, that's fine too).

Essentially, I am looking for software that can migrate many large files from a dozen or so disparate locations, organize those files by their metadata, and rename duplicate filenames to avoid overwriting.

Eg:

```
c:\music\Beatles\Yellow Submarine.mp3
c:\dad_backup\The Beatles\Yellow Submarine\Yellow Submarine.mp3
e:\music\Beatles, The\Yellow Submarine.mp3
```

would all end somewhere like:

```
m:\music\The Beatles\Yellow Submarine.mp3
m:\music\The Beatles\Yellow Submarine_1.mp3
m:\music\The Beatles\Yellow Submarine_2.mp3
```

I know it won't be perfect (based on slight differences in the metadata) but something that could get me 90% of the way there would be a great help.

Once things are sorted, I plan to use [Similarity](http://www.similarityapp.com/) to preen duplicates from the collection based on audio quality - though if there's potentially a better way to do that I'm all ears. It's just too difficult to preen with everything in different places. MediaMonkey is my music player/manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all the files have their metadata, you can use [ReNamer](https://www.den4b.com/products/renamer) for this task. You could also use a different program like [Mp3Tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/), but the ReNamer method deals with the duplicates by renaming them instead of ignoring them.

You need to add four rules to ReNamer in this order:

**1) Delete:** Delete from Position 1 until the End (skip extension)

**2) Insert:** Insert ":MP3_Title:" as Prefix (skip extension)

**3) Pascal Script :** ([source](http://www.den4b.com/wiki/ReNamer:Scripts:Serialize_duplicates))

```
var
  Files: TWideStringArray;

procedure Add(const S: WideString);
begin
  SetLength(Files, Length(Files)+1);
  Files[Length(Files)-1] := S;
end;

function Exists(const S: WideString): Boolean;
var I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I:=0 to Length(Files)-1 do
    if WideSameText(Files[I], S) then
      begin Result := True; Break; end;
end;

var
  NewFileName: WideString;
  Counter: Integer;

begin
  Counter := 2;
  NewFileName := FileName;
  while Exists(NewFileName) do
  begin
    NewFileName := WideExtractBaseName(FileName) +
      ' (' + IntToStr(Counter)+')' + WideExtractFileExt(FileName);
    Counter := Counter + 1;
  end;
  FileName := NewFileName;
  Add(FileName);
end.
```

**4) Insert:** Insert "C:\Users\YourUserName\MusicFolder:MP3_Artist:\" as Prefix (skip extension)

Drag the files you want to rename/move into the program, click **preview** to see what the files will look like and to test for errors, and if you're ok with the file names, click **rename.** I tested this process and it worked, but you could test it in small batches just in case.

Your files will have this format:

C:\Users\YourUserName\MusicFolder\The Beatles\Yellow Submarine.mp3

C:\Users\YourUserName\MusicFolder\The Beatles\Yellow Submarine(2).mp3

Edit: To clarify, this program will rename mp3 files based on the ID3 tags. You can add the files and/or folders from multiple locations (C: , D:, etc. ) by using its drag and drop interface and it will rename them and move them to a single location you specify, where the files will be organized with the format \MusicFolderOfYourChoice\Artist\Title.mp3

Any duplicate files will have a number appended at the end of the filename.

Comment: Could you expand on how it would help OP consolidate from **different folders/drives**, like `c:\music`, `c:\dad_backup`, `e:\music`

Comment: @laggingreflex I added a clarification at the bottom. What the program and this set of rules will do is organize mp3 files from multiple locations by renaming them based on their ID3 tags and moving them to a single location.